# What is the State-of-the-Art open source Voice Cloning tool right now?

Tags: natural-language-processing, speech-synthesis

I would like to clone a voice as precisely as possible. Lately, impressive models have been released that only need about 10 s of voice input (cf. https://github.com/CorentinJ/Real-Time-Voice-Cloning), but I would like to go beyond that and clone a voice even more precisely (with subsequent text-to-speech using that voice). It doesn't matter if I have to provide minutes or hours of voice inputs.